# Wrong Image Orientation Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm taking pictures on the device using:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

I also take pictures from the gallery, and both pictures taken immediately through the above code and old images taken with the device from the gallery are stored in Firebase with the wrong orientation. They show up on the device fine, and if you go to the download link it's fine.

The preview in Firebase Storage and when downloading the image using Picasso causes this problem. I'm not entirely sure, but Glide didn't have this problem I believe.. But I can't use Glide due to issues with Recyclerview flickering.

Some images are just fine orientation wise, a lot of them not taken from the device...

How can I get the correct orientation for images?